# Extremely weird proftpd behavior

Tags: mysql, debian, ftp, proftpd

I have configured proftpd + mysql and it is working

Its working perfectly despite the overcomplicated queries.

However when I enable DefaultRoot ~
It stops working and somehow reverts to some standard query, AFTER authenticating the user

### solution

`SQLAuthenticate users`
when using custom queries *AND* `DefaultRoot ~` as the latter seems to cause undefined behavior if userset is enabled..

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: the question was "why?", but now i know why, SQLAuthenticate on enables "userset" that destroys my custom queries. if you didnt comment id remove this question :) its weird that it works without `DefaultRoot` tho...